# Mixed Content errors in Swagger UI served by APIFlask

Tags: flask, https, swagger-ui, mixed-content, apiflask

New to APIFlask, but I have a small app that works fine locally. I can go to `/docs` to load Swagger UI then use that to successfully test my endpoints.

However, when I deploy it to my staging environment and use Swagger UI to hit an endpoint, I get a `NetworkError` - and if I open the browser console, I see the following error:

`Blocked loading mixed active content “http://MYHOST.com/foo”`

(I replaced the real domain name with `MYHOST` for privacy, and `foo` is an endpoint I use for testing basic health.)

The error message also includes a link to this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

I'm not an expert on this particular area, but I'm guessing it's because I'm using `http` locally, but using `https` in the staging environment, and when the Swagger UI is loaded via `https` and then tries to hit `/foo` using `http`, it triggers the Mixed Content error.

What's the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - I added `--forwarded-allow-ips="*"` to my gunicorn command line.

---

The relevant behavior is described in the [Gunicorn source](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/21.2.0/gunicorn/config.py#L1238):

> "If the source IP is permitted by `forwarded-allow-ips` (below), *and* at least one request header matches a key-value pair listed in this dictionary, then Gunicorn will set `wsgi.url_scheme` to `https`, so your application can tell that the request is secure."

This explains why I saw different behavior locally vs deployed with a real IP address, but it's still worth explaining how it specifically determines the server URL that ends up in the Swagger UI dropdown box.

---

The `apiflask.APIFlask` class determines what URL(s) to put in the dropdown box based on the `SERVERS` config setting (which is inflexible) or based on the value of `request.url_root` ([src](https://github.com/apiflask/apiflask/blob/2.0.2/src/apiflask/app.py#L818)):

```
kwargs['servers'] = [{'url': request.url_root}]
```

The `APIFlask` class inherits from `flask.Flask`, which uses a `Request` class that inherits from `werkzeug.wrappers.request.Request`, which inherits from `werkzeug.sansio.request.Request`.

You can see in `wrappers.request.Request` that:

1. The `url_root` property simply returns `self.root_url`.  ([src](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/2.3.7/src/werkzeug/wrappers/request.py#L509))
2. The `__init__` method passes the value of `environ["wsgi.url_scheme"]` as the scheme arg to the parent class.  ([src](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/2.3.7/src/werkzeug/wrappers/request.py#L113))

You can see that in `sansio.request.Request`, the `root_url` property returns the value of `self.scheme`, which is set in the `__init__` method.  ([src](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/2.3.7/src/werkzeug/sansio/request.py#L338))

---

That's the full chain of causality, more or less.